# Why is it unsafe to use Linear Congruential Generator to shuffle cards in online casino? How long will it take to crack this system?

Tags: security, random

I know that Linear Congruential Generator is not recommended where high randomness and security level are needed, but I don't know why. If I use Linear Congruential Generator to generate a random number for shuffle algorithm, is it easy to crack? If it is, how long will it take to crack it?

Comment: it depends a bit but not more than a couple of decks (2-5)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Also see Joan Boyer's [Inferring Sequences Produced by Pseudo-Random Number Generators](http://asterix.cs.gsu.edu/crypto/p129-boyar.pdf). A little research would have revealed the article rather quickly. The paper is 30 years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear congruential generators have several major flaws:

- They have very little internal state. Some generators may have as few as 64 thousand possible starting states -- as a result, using one of these would mean that there are only 64 thousand possible shuffled decks. This makes it very easy to identify which one of those decks is being used at any given point.
- Their future *and past* behavior can be perfectly determined based on their state. Once an attacker is able to gather enough information to guess the state of a LCRNG being used to shuffle cards, they can determine both what all the future shuffles will be, and what any past shuffles were.
- They frequently suffer from statistical biases. One common flaw is that low-order bits will follow a short cycle -- for instance, in many generators, the least significant bit of the raw output will flip between 1 and 0 on subsequent outputs.

The first two issues are what will cause you the most trouble here. The exact severity will depend on the size of the LCRNG's state. That being said, if a 32-bit LCRNG is being used, its state can probably be guessed given 32 bits of output state. The position of one card is roughly `lg(52) ≈ 5.7` bits of state, so the complete state can probably be guessed by seeing at least 6 (`32 ÷ 5.7 ≈ 5.6`) cards.